# ASP.NET Panel return to a certain panel after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

```
// the buttons act like a panel tab*
<asp:button ID=Button1> = hide the panel2, show the panel1 
<asp:button ID=Button2> = hide the panel1, show the panel2
  
<asp:panel ID: panel1>
    Contents of Panel 1. This is the default
</asp:panel>
    
<asp:panel ID: panel2>
    Contents of Panel 2
    <asp:button ID=Save> *response redirect to same page 
</asp:panel>
```

The default view of the page is to show `Panel1`.

How can I stay the view on `Panel2` after postback when hitting the save button? It keeps returning to `Panel1` view.

Any help/tips are appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this code..

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    <%--= hide the panel2, show the panel1 --%>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button2" Text="Button2" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
    <%--= hide the panel1, show the panel2--%>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1">
        Contents of Panel 1. This is the default
    </asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel2">
        Contents of Panel 2
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" ID="Save"  OnClick="Save_Click"/>
    </asp:Panel>


 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                panel1.Visible = true;
                panel2.Visible = false;
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }

        protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: It's still responsding to the panel1 after save postback

Comment: I run the same code its working fine. have you put this.  ````                                    if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                panel1.Visible = true;
                panel2.Visible = false;
            }